# trying to import data in pimcore from xml file

Tags: pimcore

We are trying to import as XML file having some objects in PIMCORE. The file is having around 4000 records and size is around 4mb. I want to know how to import data in pimcore from XML file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some CLI importer by your own for handle it. Pimcore don't have any feature right now to import XML files. Anyway, there is not possible to do it automatically, a cause of data complex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Import Definitions Plugin for Pimcore: https://github.com/w-vision/ImportDefinitions

It does easily import XML files as pimcore objects.

The following data types can also be imported by the Import Definitions Plugin:

- CSV
- JSON
- SQL

You can get the plugin via composer:

```
composer require w-vision/import-definitions
```

You might need to install the plugin within the Pimcore Extension Manager.